# Cox Multivariate Table Display Error and Data Loading Modification

Tags: tidyverse, survival-analysis, cox-regression

So I would like to generate a Cox PH Multivariate Analysis table like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMpiG.jpg)

I tried the following code that I found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survivalAnalysis/vignettes/multivariate.html

The code is as follows:

```
install.packages(c("tidytidbits"))
install.packages(c("survivalAnalysis"))
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytidbits)
library(survivalAnalysis)

covariate_names <- c(age="Age at Dx",
                     sex="Sex",
                     ph.ecog="ECOG Status",
                     wt.loss="Weight Loss (6 mo.)",
                     `sex:female`="Female",
                     `ph.ecog:0`="ECOG 0",
                     `ph.ecog:1`="ECOG 1",
                     `ph.ecog:2`="ECOG 2",
                     `ph.ecog:3`="ECOG 3")
survival::lung %>%
  mutate(sex=rename_factor(sex, `1` = "male", `2` = "female")) %>%
  analyse_multivariate(vars(time, status),
                       covariates = vars(age, sex, ph.ecog, wt.loss),
                     covariate_name_dict = covariate_names) ->
result
print(result)
```

However, this only generated a table in the console, but didn't plot the table on the right side of the RStudio panel.

My first question is, what do I need to change so that an actual table image is generated?

My second question is, how can this code be modified so that instead of loading the data from the "lung" dataset of the "survival" package, I can load the data from an excel spreadsheet and set it up so that it imports the data correctly?

I'm still a novice, so any feedback would be highly appreciated!

I tried to set the working directory and the data frame with an excel spreadsheet, but that didn't work